# Button dont work after adding a pop up javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a button on my HTML code that I have set to hide a certain content. However; when I added a popup feature to my code it makes the button not work.

JS for the popup:

```
$ = function(id) {
return document.getElementById(id);
}

var show = function(id) {
$(id).style.display ='block';
}
var hide = function(id) {
$(id).style.display ='none';
}
```

JS for the hide content button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#hideshow').click(function() {    
    if ($(this).text() == '▼ VIEW CONFIGURATION ▼') {      
        $(this).html('▲ HIDE CONFIGURATION ▲')
    } else {
        $(this).html('▼ VIEW CONFIGURATION ▼');
    }
    $('#topContainers').slideToggle(400);
  });
});
```

I cant figure out what in the popup JS code is causing the button not to work.

Answer (score 0):

you are using the jquery library which uses the symbol `$` and then in your popup.js you are overwriting that symbol and assigning it to a shortcut to the getElementById function, losing the reference to the jquery library.

Comment: Thank you got it!

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
$ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }
```

overrides the jQuery method and thus your code using the default `$()` doesn't work any more.

Comment: Thank you got it!